# nl2br second parameter doesn't work

Tags: php

This:

```
var_dump(nl2br("aaa\naaa", false));
```

Outputs:

```
NULL
```

I am using PHP Version 5.2.13. Doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Fine. All 3 answers maed in the same time and have a similar content.

Comment: @Alexander Phil was first. His answer appeared before the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the changelog. The second parameter was added in PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 2):

The second `false` parameter was added in PHP 5.3. Older versions of the function probably fail if passed an extra parameter they don't expect. Local experiments confirm this, the code runs fine on PHP 5.3 and fails on 5.2.10.

Answer (score 1):

Only in PHP 5.3 there are second arg in `nl2br`.